# Base url to virtual folder htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, friendly-url

I have my website `http://example.com`, I would like to redirect to a virtual folder

```
http://example.com/en (index.php?lang=$1)
```

How can I do ? :(

I tried with an

```
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/en
```

but it didn't work as expected (Error 500). I did not forget

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Can you explain the question a little more?

Comment: I have a multi language website, I need to redirect http://example.com to http://example.com/en by default :)

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/?$ /en [R,L]`